My extension show live in all connections when off
I yesterday bought this new extension and was using for some pi stuff - that's when I noticed small current in pi even though its switch is off.
When I tested it with tester, here's what is happening
(switch on main board is on in all cases here).
When switch of extension is turned off, both live and neutral show current

And when I test neutral light of extension board glows

Earth also show small current

When I switch on board
Right show live, left show neutral, earth show small current



In my house boards show live on left and extension show live on right.In my house board with tester left shows light right and earth plug show no light when switch is on(when off no plug shows light)
Had same issue with previous extension which later got burnt in power surge. Should I get my wiring checked (changing live and neutral)? Clearly can't check how dangerous it is directly?

both live and neutral show current ... the tester does not indicate current, it indicates voltage ... you used incorrect terminology in your question

what indications do you see when testing a wall outlet? ... add that info to your question

The switch may only switch one wire. If it does, in your system the switch is on neutral wire coming from the wall socket. Thus, the live wire is preset and goes to all sockects and it is possble that it capavitively couples through power supplies to low voltage devices. It may also leak via the lamp/leds/bulbs on the disconnected neutral on the extension sockets.
Please disconnect the whole extension from everything and use a multimeter to verify if it has a single pole switch or two pole switch.
If you ask if it is dangerous, I would say it can be. Most extension cords sold locally always have dual pole switch because the plugs are unpolarized - it might even be forbidden by regulations to have single pole switch with unpolarized sockets. Your extension cord might work nicely if the neutral and live were the other way around in your wall socket, or the extension cord had the single pole switch in the wire that is currently the live wire.
With dual pole switch, there would be no problem and the system would be safe regardless of your wall socket wiring.
What you seem to tell is that the extension cord swaps the pins anyway, if so then that should not happen anyway. I would blame the extension cord for swapping the live and neutral, but the switch being on neutral may be a separate issue. Perhaps the issue is how the cable is connected to plug, or how the cable is internally to the extension cord.

Thanks for your response, (dont have multimeter)should I get my live and neutral interchanged?

@UV0 No I am not saying it. I am just saying you bought a cheap extension cord and I don't know which way neutral and live should be in your country so if the problem is your wall socket or the extension cord swapping. I am simply saying such extension cords would be so much safer if they had a double pole switch, no matter where you use it.

An ad for this product says "India's first world-class spike suppressor with PCI ".
The common solution for this is to add Metal Oxide Varistors, MOVs.
Varistors common used for 240Vac have a capacitance of 150 pF which has an impedance of 15 kohms.  This would not trip an RCD unless there was an imbalance in L1-L2 leakage current.  There may be 3 MOVs installed for common mode and normal mode over voltage.   False indication with a NEON single wire tester may be suspect.   images from google
You can affect the neon's PE reference with your hand around the tester (100pF) then point or move your other hand around. You can modulate this low microamp neon intensity with the weakness of this 1-wire tester.
The Neon gas tube has no direct connection to ground and uses coil wire capacitance to use the ground capacitance in the air with a current limiting series resistor that may be over 200 k.  There can be a mismatch of the tester's ground reference concerning the PE strip ground if there is a ground fault and cause a glow due a difference in capacitance from MOV L1-GND and MOV L2-GND.
I recommend you retest it and use a proper DMM to check for PE ground continuity, leakage resistance or PE voltage on the power strip to stove PE ground.
